# Oauth2: Access and bearer-token

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, access-token, bearer-token, refresh-token

I'm new in Oauth 2.0, I'm trying to understand the differences between bearer-token and a "Classical" token.
Is also the refresh-token a bearer one?

Answer (score 0):

A refresh token is used to get a new bearer token.  So they are different. I have am not sure what you mean by a "Classical" token.

This is a good introduction to [tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/)